# Determine Username in Azure SQL Server if user is a User assigend managed identity

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-managed-identity

I connect Azure SQL Server using a user assigned managed identity from a webapp. This works fine so fare, and our logging process shall log all activities of this app (and others) in the database.

To determine the username of the current acting user, i can usuallly use in any stored procedure something like

```
SELECT @ORIGINAL_LOGIN()
```

which will return the username of the connected user.

The username of the managed identity is in my case "octservice". But when "octservice" connects, and i log its activities, the @ORIGINAL_LOGIN() Function does not returns its username, it returns something like ClientID@TenantID from the Azure AD.

How can i anyway determine the username, like it appears in SSMS ?
The ClientID@TenantID is not the USER_ID of this user.

[image]
[image]

Comment: You likely want `CURRENT_USER`, which returns the `USER` the `LOGIN` is using within the currently connected database.

Comment: No, i tried this - CURRENT_USER also retruns me ClientID@TenantID instead of the Username (in my example "octservice").

Comment: @SvenErik no, i was not able to solve it till now.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I wanted to drop the current user from the `db_owner` role after applying EFcore-migrations.

My Solution is to first check whether the value returned by `SELECT SUSER_NAME() AS Value` is the name of an azure identity using a regex:

```
(?im)^[0-9A-F]{8}-([0-9A-F]{4}-?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}@[0-9A-F]{8}-([0-9A-F]{4}-?){3}[0-9A-F]{12}$
```

then looking up the username from the table `sys.database_principals`:

```
SELECT name AS Value from sys.database_principals WHERE sid = SUSER_SID()
```

With that name, I was able to create SQL statement to drop the role member:

```
ALTER ROLE [db_owner] DROP MEMBER [{Value}]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try `SELECT SYSTEM_USER()`? It's a synonym for `SUSER_SNAME()`. I've seen it referenced once or twice with regard to managed identity.

Comment: System_User did not help in this case, it returned the same ClientID@TenantID